# Connection reset when trying to upload File to openfire server

Tags: java, file-upload, xmpp, openfire, smack

Using XEP-0363, I want to upload a file . The process is as follow:

- the client discover the upload featur
- the server respond with the upload feature's domain
- the client request a slot to xmpp server
- the xmpp server respond with the slot with the following xml :

```
<iq from='upload.montague.tld'
    id='step_03'
    to='romeo@montague.tld/garden'
    type='result'>
  <slot xmlns='urn:xmpp:http:upload:0'>
    <put url='https://upload.montague.tld/4a771ac1-f0b2-4a4a-9700-f2a26fa2bb67/tr%C3%A8s%20cool.jpg'>
      <header name='Authorization'>Basic Base64String==</header>
      <header name='Cookie'>foo=bar; user=romeo</header>
    </put>
    <get url='https://download.montague.tld/4a771ac1-f0b2-4a4a-9700-f2a26fa2bb67/tr%C3%A8s%20cool.jpg' />
  </slot>
</iq>
```

where the utls in the put and get are the urls for uploading and downloading respectively.
After that:

- the client upload the file
- when the upload is successfull, the get url will download the file .

now my problem is inn the uploading stage where an error is thrown .The relevant code is :

```
    private void apacheUpload(File file,URI url) throws Exception {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
        FileEntity reqEntity = new FileEntity(file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        put.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(put);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
        if(response == null) {
            return ;
        }
        int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (responseCode - 200 >= 100)
             throw new Exception("bad status code: " + responseCode);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println("response");
        System.out.println(responseString);
    }
```

the client error is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Connection reset
    at main.java.com.tecfrac.external.HttpFileUploadManagerUser.apacheUpload(HttpFileUploadManagerUser.java:292)
    at main.java.com.tecfrac.external.HttpFileUploadManagerUser.uploadFile(HttpFileUploadManagerUser.java:275)
    at main.java.com.tecfrac.smack.Client.uploadFile(Client.java:244)
    at main.java.com.tecfrac.smack.Client.main(Client.java:274)
```

the server error is :

```
2021.10.06 03:34:15 WARN  [socket_c2s-thread-2]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.nio.ConnectionHandler - Closing connection due to exception in session: (0x0000003D: nio socket, server, null => 0.0.0.0/0.0.  0.0:5222)
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:378) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioProcessor.read(NioProcessor.java:47) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.read(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:519) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$1200(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1222) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.process(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1211) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:683) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) ~[mina-core-2.1.3.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_202]
```

the following statement caused the error :

```
response = httpclient.execute(put);
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

the openfire fire was on another pc, so I needed to use the ip address of that pc (not localhost)